# Making a file created by an application to be shared by iTunes

Tags: ipad

How to make a file created via an ipad application to be available to iTunes.

And how to make an application support iTunes file sharing could some one give a code snippet for both these

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is set UIFileSharingEnabled to YES in your info.plist. Once that's set, anything in your app's documents folder will be accessible through iTunes.